# Read hdfs data to Spark DF without mentioning file type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there any approach to read hdfs data to spark df without explicitly mentioning file type.

```
spark.read.format("auto_detect").option("header", "true").load(inputPath)
```

We can achieve above requirement by using scala.sys.process_ or python subprocess(cmd). and splitting the extension of any part file. But without using any subprocess or sys.process, can we achieve this ..?

Comment: you cab always read file(s) as `binary` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-binaryFile.html. Actually not always, sorry, only since Spark 3.0

Comment: @mazaneicha
Okay. One more thing is that, when i'am saving DF i need to keep the format that i'am reading. If i'am reading a parquet file, process the data and save as a parquet file.

Comment: Iam new to spark. :). I'am not sure if this possible.